# Converting data.frame to data.table, perform calculation, back to data.frame, rest of script malfunctions?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataset which is a data.frame at start which I export to csv, and read in again using fread. Then it becomes a data.table. After this step, I perform a basic calculation on all values which changes all the values in one column. After this, I change the data.table back to data.frame using

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

Then I run my script. However, in the middle of the script I get the following error while performing lm.

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

I have to perform the transition of data.frame to data.table to perform the calculations. Whenever I run the script without the transition (keeping it as a data.frame, not performing the calculatons) the script runs just fine.

Any idea what can cause this error? I suspect it is in the transition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us the result of `summary(data)`?

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message.  You have missing, not-a-number or infinite response values when you fit your linear regression.  It has nothing to do with data tables.

A simple example to reproduce your problem.

```
dfr <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, Inf), x = runif(4))
lm(y ~ x, dfr)
## Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
##   NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

If the `na.action` argument to `lm` is anything other than `na.pass`, (or you didn't pass that argument and `getOption("na.action")` is not `na.pass`), then the problem is an infinite value, since `na.omit` will remove missing values, and `na.fail` gives a different error message.